# return a List<> from a model in EF MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am implementing jQuery autocomplete in a text box and I am curious if my code looks right.

Here is my textbox from my view.

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerName,  
                                      new {id = "CustByName" })
</div>
```

Here is the javascript to implement autocomplete for the textbox id.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#CustByName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Cases/FindByName", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
            data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { 
                       label: item.CustomerName, 
                       value: item.CustomerName, 
                       id: item.CustomerID }
                }))
            }
        })
    }
});
```

});

Here is the controller action called by the javascript:

```
public JsonResult FindByName(string searchText, int maxResults)
{
   CustomerFind find = new CustomerFind();
   var result = find.FindCustomerByName(searchText, maxResults);
   return Json(result);
}
```

Here is the function in CustomerFind called FindCustomerByName:

```
internal List<Models.Customer>  
               FindCustomerByName(string searchText, int maxResults)
{
        List<Models.Customer> cust = new List<Customer>();
        var result = from c in cust
                    where c.CustomerName.Contains(searchText)
                    orderby c.CustomerName 
                    select c;
        return result.Take(maxResults).ToList();
}
```

Here is what I have in my layout cshtml file for script reference.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/rls-functions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>"
```

Everything seems to work ok, except the LINQ query in `FindCustomerByName` does not return any records even though they exist.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue or suggest a better way to do autocomplete?

I have looked at numerous examples and cobbled this together.

Comment: Have you debugged this? **(1)** Set a breakpoint on your `findbyname` action method and see if it gets the right arguments. **(2)** Use firebug+firefox or Chrome(Press F12). Inspect the network to see if you request and response is generated correctly.

Comment: Look here :  http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/07/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with.html or here http://carlhoerberg.com/how-to-use-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-aspnet

Comment: Hi gideon, the findbyname action method is getting the right arguements.
It seems like FindCustomerByName LINQ is not working. The javascript gets triggered by the textbox, and it goes thru FindByName just fine, but the enumeration does not return any results in FindCustomerByName. I have verified there is data that matches the search text.

Comment: Then it's most likely that you need the AllowGet behavior as stated in answer below. If excluded the server will not send data back to the client

Comment: Thanks. I added both the class in the textboxfor, and the jsonrequestbehavior.allowget

Comment: yes, and I also have my js file that has the autocomplete code

Comment: no I am really puzzled. I followed some of your code that you provided a couple days ago and read a ton of stuff on the web, and I still don't see where my error might be. I am sure it is something on my end as I am new to jQuery and MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second update. Found a couple syntax errors

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CustByName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Cases/FindByName", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
                data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { 
                           label: item.CustomerName, 
                           value: item.CustomerName, 
                           id: item.CustomerID }
                    })); // <--- semicolon here
                }
            }); // <--- semicolon here
        },
        minLength: 3 // <-- sets the minimum number of characters to type before ajax fires
    });
});
```

Update based on OP not having a db context that he is getting data from

Here is an example of making a query to the Database using EF. A database context has to be created first and then you use that context here in code.

```
public IList<Lender> GetLenders(string partialText) {
    IList<Lender> lenders;

    // Create data connection to the LINQ to SQL class that represents the database
    using (DBDataContext dataContext = new DBDataContext()) {

        // Get all lenders where lender name contains partial text and put them into new Lender objects
        // The final call .ToList() puts all the Lender objects into a collection that can be enumerated
        lenders = (from data
                        in dataContext.LenderDBs
                    orderby data.LenderName
                    where data.IsActive == true
                        && data.LenderName.ToLower().Contains(partialText.ToLower())
                    select new Lender {
                        LenderName = data.LenderName,
                        URL = data.URL
                    }).Take(15).ToList();
    }
    return lenders;
}
```

---

Your `TextBoxFor` is missing the class that creates the Autocomplete feature `class="ui-widget"` but also make sure that you have this script in your layout for the styling of the dropdown

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerName,  
                                  new {id = "CustByName", @class = "ui-widget" })
```

And your action needs to allow for Json return by allowing the Get in the return

```
public JsonResult FindByName(string searchText, int maxResults)
{
   CustomerFind find = new CustomerFind();
   var result = find.FindCustomerByName(searchText, maxResults);
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Aside from all that the only other thing I see is `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` missing in your ajax request. Try putting an `alert(data);` just before the `response` statement in your `success` section. If that doesn't hit then Ajax is erroring

---

Also, as a separate concern, you are sending in `maxResults` to return your data, but your data is actually returning all rows where `searchText` matches and then once it gets to your client it is then taking the `maxResults`. I'd change that so that `maxResults` was part of your query so you aren't returning more data than needed. Actually, I'd put `maxResults` as a configurable option in the web.config file. The UI doesn't need to concern itself with rules like that.

I've profiled using code like your orignal and code like below. If you watch SQL Server execution the server will return all rows with match with the code you had above. But the code below will create a `Top 10` clause so that only 10 rows are returned

```
internal List<Models.Customer>  FindCustomerByName(string searchText, int maxResults)
{
        List<Models.Customer> cust = new List<Customer>();
        var result = (from c in cust
                    where c.CustomerName.Contains(searchText)
                    orderby c.CustomerName 
                    select c).Take(maxResults).ToList();
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting data :)

I did this:
   `code internal List<Models.Customer> FindCustomerByName(string searchText, int maxResults)`
            {
            List<Models.Customer> result;

            using (cummins_sqldb dataContext = new cummins_sqldb())
                {

                result = (from c in dataContext.Customers
                          where c.CustomerName.Contains(searchText)
                          orderby c.CustomerName
                          select c).Take(maxResults).ToList();
                }
            return result;

            }

Comment: well, not getting the actual autocomplete yet, but a step closer. Now I need to see what the ajax response looks like in the js

Comment: Yeah, put an `alert(data);` right before the `response` and see what you have, also using Chrome/IE9 dev tools or Firebug you can see the response values

Comment: the alert(data) is not even firing. Obviously my js is called the controller/action, but I am not sure why I could not be able to see the response.

Comment: Did you add the contentType line to the ajax call? `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: Ok, add this to your call `error: function(response) { alert(response); },` To see if there is an error with the call

Comment: Ok, well we've determined that there is an error, what browser are you using? If you are in Chrome or IE9 hit F12 to bring up Dev tools and refresh the page, in Chrome there will be a little red stop sign on lower right if there is an error, click that to get more info, it will point out what script and what line the error is on

Comment: In Chrome it is showing a GET error 500 (internal server error) for the url of my controller action FindByName

Comment: it is inside the ajax call it looks like.

Comment: No, not in the ajax call itself but on the server side, we've established that your call is being made, that it is receiving the correct data to search by, it's calling the db and getting data and filling the list with items. There's something amiss with the webserver itself with returning that data.... see here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: ok, I am using IIS Express...I wonder if it is a permission issue?

Comment: GET http://localhost:51091/Cases/FindByName?searchText=Mt+Clemens+Branc&maxResults=10 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.support.ajax.d.ajaxTransport.send jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.extend.ajax jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
$.autocomplete.source rls-functions.js:15
d.widget._search jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js:377
d.widget.search jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js:377
(anonymous function)

Comment: First thing I would do is upgrade your jquery scripts. The latest jQuery is 1.7.2 and jQueryUI is 1.8.18 as hosted by Google's CDN. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: If you switch your webserver (in the project properties of the mvc project) to local dev server, does that alleviate the problem?

Comment: Ok, I changed it to the local dev server and the 500 Internal Server error says "failed to load resource". Perhaps js lib is not getting loaded. I will change them to cdn and see what happens.

Comment: Yep that's what it is, some library isn't getting loaded, verify each script, the path and if it's physically there if it's not cdn

Comment: @Ryan if this answer and the other answer of mine helped you solve your problem would you mind marking them as checked

Comment: Your answers have been very helpful! I appreciate the time you gave me. I changed the js references to cdn in my layout cshtml. Watching in the chrome developer tools as I step through the breakpoints in C#  the error does not occur until the json data is returned to the javascript ajax function. I says the resource could not be loaded, so I am wondering if it is the jquery ui lib. I still can't figure out why it would not work...

Comment: Yeah if you don't mind maybe updating your question with what you have in your layout. If I can see the script tags you have maybe I can glean what the error source is. You've done a really good job as you say from "cobbling it all together" and I'm sure you've learned a lot along the way!

Comment: Ok, I added those lines to my sample solution that I have on GitHub and they work fine. Except for that last script you have of course, that looks like some custom script of yours. Maybe pull that line out and anything that uses it.

Comment: that custom script is what holds the autocomplete code. Should I put that autocomplete function somewhere else? Interestingly there is a datetimepicker function in that js file that works fine on the same view that I am having the autocomplete issue.

Comment: I would put that line in the actual view not the layout page. So just after your `@model ...` line drop in that script `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/rls-functions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` also noticed there is a doublequote hanging at the end of that line that needs to go away... see your update in the question you have `</script>"` that doublequote could be a big problem

Comment: @Ryan see my update in my answer, I found a couple syntax errors as well

Comment: No dice! This is really frustrating. The doublequote was a mistake on my part in the edit of the post.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, I updated the js code with the syntax changes you post, and now the error is gone! I don't see any autocomplete working however.

Comment: Ok, so now there's no error, place this above response in the success section `alert(data[0].CustomerName);` that should give you the first record in the return

Comment: getting failed to load resource again, after check all my syntax

Comment: Ok gotcha, well I think we've exhausted this question. Let's close this question out since we fixed the original problem which was no data getting returned. If you want to zip up the solution and email it to me I can have a deeper look. email address is in my profile.

Comment: your help has been greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem, this is all fun to me!

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching your result from an empty list:

```
List<Models.Customer> cust = new List<Customer>();
```

You probably need something like:

```
List<Models.Customer> cust = .......  <- call your db code here.
```

Comment: +1 Good catch, he's not even making a call to the db that I can see.

Comment: Thanks John. I am not sure I understand. I should not use
    new List<Customer>();?

Comment: You should, it's just empty according to the code here... we don't see any code where you get a list of Customers from your Db with a dbcontext... I'll update my answer with example